# About how nwak

Tags: shell, unix

there is a file the content like

```
 nawk  -v v1=$value1 -v v2=$value2 
                      'BEGIN {FS=OFS=",";

                      if ($7=v1 && test v2="ad"){
                         $19=4;
                         $20=1 ;   
                     }elif( $7=va1 && test v2="ac"){
                         $19=4;
                         $20=4;
                     }
                 } 1 ' $file > $file.result
```

when i run up script why there is error "n**awk: no program given**"

Comment: try to include `v1=$value1 -v v2=$value2 ` inside the quotes, nawk expects the whole program to be between quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put one `'`(single quote) at first line:

```
nawk  -v v1=$value1 -v v2=$value2 '
    REST of COMMAND
'
```

Comment: hi,
In my code the code  observers this rule. but it not work. why, 
inline`
'BEGIN {FS=OFS=",";

                      if ($7=v1 && test v2="ad"){
                         $19=4;
                         $20=1 ;   
                     }elif( $7=va1 && test v2="ac"){
                         $19=4;
                         $20=4;
                     }
                 } 1 '
`

Comment: thanks very much,  it's work now awe of the quote. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, follow this question,
if ($7=v1 && test v2="ad"){
                         $19=4;
                         $20=1 ;   
                     }elif( $7=va1 && test v2="ac"){
                         $19=4;
                         $20=4;
if...elif  give syntax error. what can i do for it?

Comment: please learn to post new questions, including sample data, expected output from that sample data, the code you have written and error messages that you are getting, rather than continue the question of a thousand parts in comments!;-)! OK? +1 for formatting your first question, having same code and an error message. Good luck.